# is_category() in pre_get_posts strange error

Tags: categories, query, pre-get-posts

I have a function that sets posts_per_page option depending on the category viewed.

I discovered and error which I can't really understand: first this is how I get the error:

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {

    if ( !is_admin() && is_category(4)) {

    // Leaving this empty or with content

    }

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

So I get an error there if WP_Debug is turn to true and when I access a non-exixting category.
So if I enter `http://localhost/zz/category/uncategorized` there is no problem but if I enter for example `http://localhost/zz/category/aaaaaaaa` (Category aaaaaaaa doesn't exist), It gets correctly to the 404 page but throws these errors:

```
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\zz\wp-includes\query.php on line 3420
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\zz\wp-includes\query.php on line 3422
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\zz\wp-includes\query.php on line 3424
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Might this just be a result of not using quotes? Like this `is_category( '4' )`.

Comment: is_category( '4' ) , is_category( 'house' )  throws the same errors

Comment: The errors only appear if I check is_category() in the pre_get_posts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit of investigation...

If you pass a category to `is_category` it uses `get_queried_object` to grab data-- [see the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3416). `get_queried_object` [returns `NULL`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3247) for categories that do not exist. You can demonstrate that with:

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
  var_dump(get_queried_object());
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

Load a valid category archive and then an invalid one.

The `is_category` method does not check to see whether it has a valid object before trying to use that object, hence the error. I would definitely consider that a bug.

The only way I see around it is to check for the existence of the category first:

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {

    if ( !is_admin() && term_exists(4,'category') && $query->is_category(4)) {

    // Leaving this empty or with content

    }

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

Or handle the logic yourself:

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category()) {
      $qobj = get_queried_object();
      if (!empty($qobj)
        && (isset($qobj->taxonomy) && 'category' == $qobj->taxonomy && 4 == $qobj->term_id)
      ) {
        var_dump($qobj);
      }
    // Leaving this empty or with content

    }

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. Caveat emptor. No refunds.

Comment: in your 2nd example, it should be `$query->is_category(4)`, or you'll modify every query on the page.

Comment: Fixed, thanks @Milo. Now I have to look over it again to see if I screwed up anything else :)

Comment: +1 I was just looking at the source too, I guess that's what can be done. Or live with the message, because it isn't a real problem.

Comment: @Alvaro : I am not sure that it is you that is doing something wrong.

Comment: @ialocin : if logging is enabled on the server there has to be a performance penalty for things like this, as there is at the very least a disk write. The penalty is probably not significant for most sites but has to be there.

Comment: I cant pass an array in term_exists(HERE,'category') right?

Comment: You're of course absolutely right. Only thing that makes me wonder is, why isn't the check part of the core code.

Comment: @ialocin : just a bug I think. I am going to check trac for this. It is a very simple patch.

Comment: @Alvaro, no. `term_exists` does not take an array.