# Reverse order of posts in a certain taxonomy archive?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hooks, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type `message` which has a custom taxonomy called `series`. Is there a way to reverse the date order of the posts in just that archive (oldest first)? I want to continue to show newest first in the basic all-messages archive as well as archives based on other taxonomies.

There are plenty of examples of how to do it for all archives, like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'change_post_order');
function change_post_order($query){
    $query->set('order','ASC');
    $query->set('orderby','date');
}
```

But I don't know how to limit it to archives of just the `series` taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but can you do:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'change_post_order');
function change_post_order($query){
    if($query->is_tax('series')) {
        $query->set('order','ASC');
        $query->set('orderby','date');
    }
}
```

Based of [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125041/is-category-in-pre-get-posts-strange-error#answer-125044) and [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_category/).

Comment: That has no effect, and I'm not surprised. It's not a category term called "series", but a whole custom taxonomy (not categories or tags) called "series" with its own terms.

Comment: @OsakaWebbie Sorry if I'm still not understanding but in that case would you not use [is_tax](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_tax/) instead?

Comment: Yes, `is_tax('series')` is exactly what I needed! Edit your answer and I'll accept it as the official answer.

Comment: There you go, glad it helped :)